# Dynamically adding component Vs Statically creating all the components in ReactJS for performance

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a Document component in ReactJS. This document component has 10 different other child components.

```
<Document>
<Header/>
<Body>
<Image/>
<Paragraph1/>
<Paragraph2/>
<Paragraph3/>
<Paragraph4/>
<Paragraph5/>
<Paragraph6/>
<Paragraph6/>
</Body>
</Document>
```

The **Paragraph** child components have content, some words in the content have a 'help' or 'meaning' link next to the word shown with a **?** mark. When the user click the **?**, a [bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) is shown. These popovers can have large content, so I decided not to build the Paragraph components with all the popover components (I used [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)) because the DOM can be large and can effect the scrolling performance (framerate of the browser).

Instead I thought about rendering the paragraph again when the user clicks the **?** Clicking the **?** will trigger a state change which ultimately renders the paragraph with the popover. With this approach, no popovers are created during the first rendering of the whole document.

I'm not sure what is the best pattern to follow to do something like this in ReactJS? Generate the large DOM with all the popovers (large DOM) or create the popover only when the user takes action (smaller DOM)?